# Need help in splitting a string in variable and assign it's parts to an array

Tags: php, string

One of my variable in my PHP script produce strings like:

```
'something/test/1'
```

I want to split that kind of strings through the keyword `/` and then assign those parts to an array in PHP by using `preg_match` or something else.
The output should look like:

```
array(
    '0' => 'something',
    '1' => 'test,
    '2' => '1'
);
```

Comment: PHP's documentation is very good, you would have easily found such a function looking at the "string functions" page http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
<?php
$te="something/test/1";
$ka=explode('/',$te);
print_r($ka);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = explode('/', $string);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a php function called `explode` that does exactly what you want. [manual here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 4):

Just use `$array=explode('/',$string)`.  The [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function does the splitting and returns the array that you want.